# threads and synchronization example

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java. Below is a code as an example of threads and synchronization.

```
public class A implements Runnable{
    public synchronized void run(){

        /*
        some code here
         */

    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A obj1 = new A();
        Thread t = new Thread(obj1);
        A obj2 = obj1;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj2);
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Now will this two threads block each other for same lock or will they get two different locks?

Thank you!!

Comment: Why don't you run the code yourself and find the answer to your question?

Comment: @Paul - because that won't give a **definitive** answer.  It will tell you that it *looks like* one thread blocks the other, *each time* you run it.  But doesn't tell the OP that there is *actual* blocking going on (as distinct from some other hypothetical mechanism that the OP isn't aware of), or that the blocking *always* happens.

Comment: @Paul - what I'm trying to say is that treating synchronization as a black box and trying to figure out how to use it experimentally is *not a sound approach*.  You are liable to get all sorts of false notions ... that will bite you later on.

Comment: @StephenC, it would be better for him to run it, see what happens, come up with some thoughts on what's going on, test those hypotheses, _then_ ask a question about it.  He could have run the code and said, "Based on what I saw, I think this is going on, am I right?"  This seems more likely a thought experiment (because launching two threads with one `Runnable` makes no sense) - putting a little thought and effort into it is a great way to learn. Nobody learns (well) by being told the answer.

Comment: @Paul - People **DO** learn by having the answer **explained** to them in detail.  If they properly read and understand the explanations, then they learn well.  That's why we recommend people read text books.

Comment: @Paul - please re-read my original comment.  I'm not saying "don't do the experiment".  I'm saying that the experiment won't (really) answer the question.  At best it will provide supporting evidence ... provided that it is done right.  At worst, an experiment on synchronization done incorrectly will provide invalid "evidence" for a false conclusion.

Comment: @StephenC No one every became a good (or even decent) programmer from just reading a textbook.  I'm not saying he shouldn't have asked; I'm saying he should have run the code first and formulated a thought (which is the result of thinking) about what happened instead of asking, "hey, what happens when I run this code?"  Yes, please, everyone ask questions (I do all the time), that's what SO is for, but at least think a little first.

Comment: I don't know where you got this example, but it's a very very poor example.  It does work, but you'll never see anything close to that in real life.  You never make the Runnable.run() `synchronized` in real life because you'll always stick to one instance of a Runnable for one thread.

Comment: @toto2 - Ummm ... I've seen `SO` Questions asking about sharing a Runnable between multiple threads ... so you *may* see this in real life.  (I agree it is a bad idea though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(First, please stick to the Java coding conventions.  A class name should **always** start with a capital letter.  No exceptions.)

Only one of the threads will execute the `run()` method at a time.

The `A.run()` method is an instance method, and it is declared as `synchronized`.  These two facts  mean that it will acquire a lock on `this` (i.e. the instance of `A`) before entering the method body, and release it on exiting.  In short, `run()` locks `this`.

So in your main program you are creating a single `A` instance and passing it as the `target` object for two threads.  They both need to execute the `run()` method on the same object, and this cannot happen at the same time ... by the reasoning of the previous paragraph.

This does not *necessarily* mean that one thread will block the other.  It is also possible that the first thread to be started will have completed its `run()` call before the second thread is ready to try the call.  But we can say ... *definitively* ... that the two threads' calls to `run()` will NOT overlap in time.

Answer (score 0):

They will block each other, since they're both `synchronized` on the same object.

For example, this program:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final Runnable r =
            new Runnable()
            {
                public synchronized void run()
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        try
                            { Thread.sleep(1000L); }
                        catch(final InterruptedException ie)
                            { throw new RuntimeException(ie); }
                    }
                }
            };
        new Thread(r).start();
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
}
```

will print 0 through 9, pausing for a second after number, and then do it again. It will *not* interlace the two sets of numbers.

Comment: But your thread is on same object "r"; in my case am making shallow copy of obj1 (obj2 = obj1) and acquiring lock on both, will it work same?

Comment: @anjali, you aren't making a copy of an object, you're making a copy of the *reference* to an object.

Comment: @MikeDaniels yeah, but does it work same? i mean acquiring lock by obj1 and obj2 is same?

Comment: @anjali obj1 and obj2 are the same object; `obj1 == obj2`. The analogy is that there's a house somewhere, that's your object. You never refer to it by the physical house itself (your business card would be huge!), but by its address. You can copy the text of that address as many times as you want, but all those slips of paper still refer to the same one house. In your code, obj1 and obj2 are the slips of paper that refer to the object created by `new a()`. The line `a obj2 = obj1` just copied the address written on `obj1` to a new slip of paper called `obj2` -- it didn't make a new house.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of room... the last piece of the puzzle is that the synchronization is against the house, not the slip of paper -- it's against the actual object, not against the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronization forces the threads to run in order (block).**

Synchronization, by definition, means that a method is run "one at a time". The first thread to be executed (likely "t") will thus complete before the 2nd thread (probably "t1")'s run() method is entered.

**To test the synchronization effects:**

The best experiment to run will be to fill the run() method with a call to

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Then run your code with, and without the "synchronized" keyword, and time the programs execution .

Answer (score 0):

The output of this code is getting intermixing of thread1 and thread0

```
package oopd;
/**
*
* @author mani deepak
*/
public class Oopd {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Deepak d,d1;
    d=new Deepak();
    d1=new Deepak();
    Thread t,t1;
    t=new Thread(d);
    t1=new Thread(d1);
    t.start();
    t1.start();
}
}

class Deepak implements Runnable
{
@Override
public synchronized void run()
{
    String s=Thread.currentThread().getName();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        try
        {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        System.out.println(s+" "+i);
    }
}
}
```